# Pusher API - Messages Per Minute

Tags: pusher

I implemented Pusher API in a live chat recently.

I launched a Startup package of Pusher yesterday. After 4 hours of being live, I receive an email that my account is reaching the cap on usage.

I logged in and looked at the stats, to discover that the Messages per Minute were between 5,000 and 20,000.

I don't understand how this is possible. I have around 100-150 connections open.

Why is the message count so high?

Armin

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer myself! :)

Here is the link for anyone who may have the same problem:

https://docs.messagebird.com/pusher/channels/channels/limits/how-is-my-message-count-calculated-in-channels

Basically, if you have 100 users subscribed into a channel, and 1 message is sent, it counts are 100 messages being sent since each user would have to be notified.

Bottom line is to properly filter your channels.